# Graph File Format that supports list as attributes

Tags: graph, file-format, graphml

I'd like to store a graph to a file. Usually I would do that in GraphML.
But my nodes have non-scalar properties (e.g. the property "hobby" of node "Alice" has the values ["swimming", "reading"]).
As defined in the [GraphML specification](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/primer/graphml-primer.html), properties of nodes may only be scalars, not lists.
I looked around and did not find any graph file format that supports lists as properties.
Does anybody know such a format?

Cheers,

Manuel

Answer (score 0):

Since GraphML is a type of XML, you can use a custom XML schema to be able to add in your own custom properties to GraphML, which could include adding lists.

[Extending GraphML](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/primer/graphml-primer.html#EXT) and [W3Schools Schema Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/default.asp)